# nginx rewrite or location

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm migrating an old site to a new structure, and have a bunch of these type rewrites:

```
location / {
 rewrite ^/foo.html /legacy-page? permanent;
 rewrite ^/bar.html /legacy-page? permanent;
 rewrite ^/org.html /legacy-page? permanent;
 rewrite ^/directory/foo.html /legacy-page? permanent;
 rewrite ^/directory2 /legacy-page? permanent;
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

Is there a better / more efficient way to handle those /legacy-page rewrites?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rewrite ^/(foo|bar|org|directory/foo).html /legacy-page? permanent;
rewrite ^/directory2 /legacy-page2 permanent;
```

Comment: Thanks, cjc. is there a directory equivalent?  that is every request to /directory2 , /directory3 , /etc. goes to /legacy-page?  

and - was the second rule destination (legacy-page2) a typo?